# Does "Forgive me" need a pronoun before the object?

Tags: grammaticality

I used to say "Forgive my behavior" and I am quite sure you can say this in English. I am quite sure, if you need to use that phrase too often, there might be a social issue and any grammar issues are less important. However, in a recent conversation, just before sending out a message to a lot of our customers, I suggested using the following sentence to ask for understanding in case the message was received multiple times:

> Please forgive us the duplicates.

A colleague pointed out that this is not proper English and we ended up with

> Please forgive us *for* any duplicates.

Which definitely sounds better.

Is the former version of this sentence (without the pronoun) really invalid? Does it sound bad to a native speaker? Would the following, without pronoun, work too?

> Please forgive us any duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please forgive us any duplicates.

As far as I'm aware, this is not idiomatic. However, there are two options here, relatively close to what you want.

[When looking up "forgive" in the OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/forgive), notice that there are two different objects that you can use:

> - I'll never **forgive David** for the way he treated her.
> - You will have to **forgive my suspicious mind**

You can forgive a **person**, or you can forgive a **mistake**. Both are correct, as long as they're the object of the sentence.

That means that you have options too:

> - Please **forgive us** [for any duplicates].
> - Please **forgive any duplicates** [made by us].

Both mean the same thing, assuming that "us" is the only party who could be responsible for making duplicates.
Otherwise, if another party could also possibly be responsible for making duplicates, then "forgive us" seems to omit forgiving the other party, whereas "forgive any duplicates" covers both you and the other party.

Comment: I immediately thought of "Forgive us our trespasses" in the traditional English version of the Lord's Prayer. This version, although much-loved, contains several forms of words that we don't use today. I agree with Flater's suggestions.

Comment: @KateBunting Came here to say this, except that my ancestors would have it "forgive us our debts". Grammatically, this is similar to the asker's original sentence.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. However, the question was whether the "for" between "forgive us" and the object is required.

Comment: @Kariem: See KateBunting (and MetaEd)'s comment. There are occurrences of "Forgive us [the object]" which omits the "for", but this phrasing is no longer used nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. replace the entire sentence with: "We apologise for any duplication" which is the true intent of the original sentence.